# MySQL - listing multiple properties

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database: `AppropriateFor` and `AquariumModel`, shown below. They share three keys - AquariumType, Salinity, and Volume. I am attempting to find all aquarium models that are considered appropriate for more than one species. I'm struck trying to correctly count the primary tuple in `AppropriateFor` and then join it with the `AquariumModel` table.

The AppropriateFor table has four columns: speciesName, aquariumType, salinity, volume:

```
RED-BELLIED PACU                AGGRESSIVE  FRESHWATER  300
GOLDEN MORAY EEL            AGGRESSIVE  MARINE      25000
NURSE SHARK                 AGGRESSIVE  MARINE      25000
COMMON TOADFISH             COMMUNITY   BRACKISH    150
DRAGON GOBY                 COMMUNITY   BRACKISH        150
BRONZE CORYDORAS            COMMUNITY   FRESHWATER  250
COMMON DISCUS               COMMUNITY   FRESHWATER  250
SPOTTED RAPHAEL             COMMUNITY   FRESHWATER  250
UPSIDE-DOWN CATFISH         COMMUNITY   FRESHWATER  250
BLUESPOTTED ANGELFISH       COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
CHALK BASS                  COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
FLAME ANGELFISH             COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
ORIENTAL SWEETLIPS          COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
ROUND STINGRAY              COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
ROYAL ANGELFISH             COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
TEIRA BATFISH               COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000
BARTLETTS ANTHIAS           REEF        MARINE      75000
BELLUS ANGELFISH            REEF        MARINE      75000
CHALK BASS                  REEF        MARINE      75000
COPPERBANDED BUTTERFLYFISH  REEF        MARINE      75000
MANDARINFISH                    REEF        MARINE      75000
COMMON TOADFISH             SPECIES     BRACKISH    100
GREEN SPOTTED PUFFER        SPECIES     BRACKISH    100
REEDFISH                    SPECIES     BRACKISH        100
ELECTRIC EEL                    SPECIES     FRESHWATER  500
ORNATE BICHIR               SPECIES     FRESHWATER  500
REEDFISH                    SPECIES     FRESHWATER  500
BRAZILIAN SEAHORSE          SPECIES     MARINE      10000
```

AquariumModel has four columns as well: aquariumType, salinity, volume, price:

```
AGGRESSIVE  BRACKISH    125    200
AGGRESSIVE  FRESHWATER  300    500
AGGRESSIVE  MARINE      25000  4500
COMMUNITY   BRACKISH    150    250
COMMUNITY   FRESHWATER  250    400
COMMUNITY   MARINE      50000  7000
REEF        MARINE      75000  10000
SPECIES     BRACKISH    100    150
SPECIES     FRESHWATER  500    800
SPECIES     MARINE      10000  3000
```

Comment: OP, I know my answer has already been accepted, but I added an SQL Fiddle for you as well as a comment on your database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can start by joining the two tables together on the values that you need, which would start like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM aquariummodel am 
JOIN appropriatefor af ON am.aquariumtype = af.aquariumtype AND am.salinity = af.salinity AND am.volume = af.volume;
```

Then, you want to group by all the values in aquarium type, and use the condition that the count is greater than 1. So I would then change the query to this:

```
SELECT am.*, COUNT(*) AS numFishAppropriateFor
FROM aquariummodel am
JOIN appropriatefor af ON am.aquariumtype = af.aquariumtype AND am.salinity = af.salinity AND am.volume = af.volume
GROUP BY am.aquariumtype, am.salinity, am.volume
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

**EDIT**
Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfbe2/1) to demonstrate that it works.

If I may, I would like to comment on the design of your database.

In the appropriate for table, you have several columns that are repeated from the aquariummodel table. I would add a primary key to your aquariummodel table (like an auto_increment id) and use that id in the appropriate for table. That way, aquariummodel would have 5 columns, but appropriatefor could be cut down to two columns: `speciesname` and `aquariummodel_id`. Just a suggestion though.

Comment: Working on SQL Fiddle to test now. Just need time to input data.